# How to find the cell based on arithmetic expression in the corresponding row

Tags: google-sheets

what the formula may be used to find the "Label" with the corresponding "Value" bigger than "Inquiry"

[image]

Comment: Hi and welcome. Have you read [Vlookup next largest value](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23661021/1330560) on stackoverflow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete everything from Column E, including the header in E1. Then place the following formula in E1:

`=ArrayFormula({"Header Text";IF(D2:D="",,IF(D2:D>MAX(B2:B),"Out Of Range",IF(D2:D<B2,A2,VLOOKUP(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(D2:D,{B2:B,ROW(A2:A)},2,TRUE),9^9)+IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(D2:D,B2:B,1,FALSE)),1,0),{ROW(A2:A),A2:A},2,FALSE))))})`

You may replace "Header Text" inside the formula with whatever you want as your real header.

After that, here is a brief description of what happens:

• If any cell in D2:D is blank, the corresponding cell in E2:E will be left blank.

• If any value in D2:D exceeds your `MAX` value in B2:B or is not a numeric value, the formula will return "Out of Range."

Otherwise...

• The inner `VLOOKUP` returns the row number of the value that is equal to or *smaller than* the target value.

• The outer `VLOOKUP` looks up that row number plus 0 (if the previous `VLOOKUP` return result was exact) or plus 1 (if the previous `VLOOKUP` return result was not exact) and returns the Column-A value for the that row number.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you, Eric!

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Just to round things out...

Nothing like the error-checking and `arrayformula` of @ErikTyler but possible solutions all the same. Maybe useful for someone in the future.

**QUERY**
`=query(A2:B6,"select A where B >"&D2&" limit 1")`

- use `limit 1` to return a single value

**INDIRECT/ADDRESS/MATCH**
`=(indirect(address(match(D2,$B$1:$B$6,1)+1,1,4)))`

- `MATCH` with search type = "1" ... "finds the largest value less than or equal to search_key when range is sorted in ascending order", and then we "+1" (add one) to get the next highest value.
- `ADDRESS` takes the row number from `MATCH`, Column = 1 (Column A) to return value, such as A5
- `INDIRECT` return the value of the address.

**IFERROR/VLOOKUP/INDIRECT/MATCH**
`= iferror(vlookup(D2,B:B,1,0),indirect("A"&match(D2,B:B)+1))`

- `IFERROR` allows a result if `VLOOKUP` fails
- `VLOOKUP` = standard lookup
- `INDIRECT/MATCH` is a variation of a theme of the `INDIRECT/ADDRESS/MATCH` used above.

---

**EXAMPLES**

All the formulas were entered in row#2, and then copied down to row#5.

[image: snapshot]